# Selenium IDE: cannot run a test case or switch to the command table

Tags: firefox, testing, selenium

I've written a test case using the Selenium IDE. I would like to run the test (using the play button) and I would like to switch to the Table tab so I can see the commands.

As seen in the screenshot, I can neither click the play button nor switch to the Table tab. Why?

[image: selenium capture]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can execute test only when your IDE is set for Selenese (HTMl format) and not any other code format. Change it to Selenese (HTML) as following and it should work -

[image]

> On a different note, do you know Selenium questions would have their dedicated home at - https://sqa.stackexchange.com/
>   You might like to post your Selenium question here.

Answer (score 1):

You can only run tests in Selenium IDE in the table format. You probably can't switch to the table format because it is a custom script and the IDE doesn't know how to interpret it. The IDE is fragile and the format switcher is only designed for you to get a recorded script into an exportable format. It isn't designed to go the other way.

Answer (score 1):

Shalom,

The script in the image you have is not what the IDE uses to execute its tests. A test that you record will initially be in "HTML" table format and if you want to use your tests with other languages you will then convert it by either "Save Test Case As..." or "Export Test Case As...". It looks like you chose to view your script in Python. To run this you will probably need to execute it like you do any other Python code. I've used my tests in Java and Ruby IDEs.